# any intersection point (if it exists) of H ∩ M is also constructible?

Tags: geometry

call a real number constructible if it can be obtained using whole numbers and a finite number of applications of operations.

Given the equation of the circle H with centre $(h, k)$ and radius $r$ is $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 = r^2,$$ consider also the line $M$ defined by $ax + by = c$.

Suppose $a, b, c, h, k, r$ are all constructible. Why are any intersection points (if they
exists) of $H \cap M$ also constructible?

What is meant by constructible. Does anyone have any hint?

Answer (score 1):

The core of your question seems to be the term “operation”. I take it that in this context, “operation” includes the intersection of a line and a circle *by definition*. So there isn't much to proove, unless you have a different set of operations which explicitely does *not* include that specific operation. In that case, you'd have to be more specific as to what operations *are* included.

The intuition is that a constructible number is a number which might occur as a coordinate of a point if all you have to start with is e.g. the unit square and construction tools like ruler and compass. The construction performed with these tools is assumed to be perfectly accurate. Some numbers, transcendental ones like $\pi$ or $e$ in particular, but also higer-degree roots like $\sqrt[7]{5}$, simply cannot be constructed using these tools, and thus are not constructible.